# Importing issue with tensorflow in Python 3.5.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip, python-import

When I import tensorflow in **Python 3.5.3**, it gives me following:

ERROR:

> No module named **_pywrap_tensorflow**
>
> Unless you are using bazel, you
>   should not try to import tensorflow from its source directory; please
>   exit the tensorflow source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter
>   from there.

I installed **tensorflow-0.12.0** using the following command:

> python -m pip install --upgrade
>   https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0-py3-none-any.whl

Comment: Did you run python under tensorflow's install directory? What operating system are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 Pro (32 bit)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Python 3.5.3 is supported for Tensorflow, then install Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable and try this command (note that you also need to uninstall the current Tensorflow first):

```
python -m pip install --upgrade  https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

Update: Go to https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tensorflow to check for available built that works for you.

Comment: It gave me the following error: `tensorflow-0.12.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

Comment: Well, I don't seem to find any wheel for **32 bit Windows**. Is there any other way.  :-(

Comment: Well, then you should probably find a 64-bit machine to work with Tensorflow, they only support 64-bit laptop/desktop.

Comment: @MelvinAbraham Install 64-bit Python. TF doesn't work in 32-bit mode.

Comment: Even in my 64-bit Windows 10, I'm struggling to install it. Gives me the same error: `...not supported wheel on this platform`