# Errors while importing tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I tried several things… started to read most of the Q&A but I am still facing following issue if I try to import tensorflow:

```
Users\XYZ>python
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Eine DLL-Initialisierungsroutine ist fehlgeschlagen.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Eine DLL-Initialisierungsroutine ist fehlgeschlagen.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I installed Python 3.5 (64bits) / pandas / matplotlib / datetime /urllib / os / numpy abd tried to install tensorflow ==> but only tensorflow failed, rest went well

I tried the same installation with Python 3.6 and 3.7 but without any success.

Is there a bulletproofed way to do the installation successful?

Thanks a lot in advance for your support.

Comment: This looks like a bad install. Careful about 32 bits and 64 bits. Give more details about what you have tried.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49610858/importing-issue-with-tensorflow-in-python-3-5-3. Hope this helps.